# Trying to loop through array of questions one by one

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple yes/no questionnaire with a for loop, but I can't quite figure out how to make the program move to the next question when you hit yes or no. (`var answ` just records the amounts of yes and no's)

```
var quesBox = ["Are you hungry?", "Are you smart?","Do you like dogs?", "Are you cool?"]
var noReady = "Go away";
var answ = {
    'yes': 0,
    'no': 0
}

yes.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (yes.style.display="block"){
        for(let i=0; i < 1; i++) {
            ques.innerHTML = (quesBox[i]);
            answ['yes'] += 1;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: What is yes? The one with which you are attaching the event listener

Comment: use variable for current question index and increase on yes/no click event

Comment: yes is just a variable that's connected to the id of a button @AshayMandwarya

Comment: could you write out what the current question variable would look like please @YasharPanahi

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition assigns `yes.style.display` to `"block"` with `=` operator.

```
yes.style.display="block"
```

Use comparison operator `==` or strict comparison `===` to compare values.

You can use `.shift()` and `.push()` to rotate elements of the array from index `0` to index at `.length - 1` of the array.

```js
var quesBox = ["Are you hungry?", "Are you smart?", "Do you like dogs?", "Are you cool?"]
var noReady = "Go away";
var answ = {
  'yes': 0,
  'no': 0
}

yes.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (yes.style.display === "block") {
      ques.innerHTML = quesBox.shift();
      quesBox.push(ques.innerHTML);
      answ['yes'] += 1;
  }
})
```

```css
#yes {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="yes" style="display:block">click</div>
<div id="ques"></div>
```

Comment: Why the strict comparison, or even the comparison for the if statement. I've only been programming with JavaScript for about a week and a half and I just started with for loops.

Comment: @TheNuthouse One general purpose of an [`if..else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) condition is to compare values, not assign values _"The if statement executes a statement if a specified condition is truthy. If the condition is falsy, another statement can be execute"_ Technically [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) can be performed within `if()` _"The basic assignment operator is equal (`=`), which assigns the value of its right operand to its left operand. "_.

Comment: @TheNuthouse What is the expected result of `if (yes.style.display="block"){}`?

Comment: I was just looking for a statement that's already true to start my if statement. I'd be happy to know if there's a better way. @guest271314

Comment: @TheNuthouse Ok. Ignore that part of the answer. Does the code output the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this. Have a global variable i. Whenever the user answers the question, increment i and the count of yes and no. You don't even need a for loop.

```
enter code here
 var quesBox = ["Are you hungry?", "Are you smart?","Do you like dogs?", "Are you cool?"]
 var noReady = "Go away";
 var answ = {
    'yes': 0,
    'no': 0
 };
 let i = 0;

 yes.addEventListener("click", function() {    
       if(i>=quesBox.length)  return;  
       ques.innerHTML - quesBox[i];
       answ['yes'] += 1;
       i++;
 });
 no.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(i>=quesBox.length)  return;
    ques.innerHTML - quesBox[i];
    answ['no'] += 1;
    i++;
});
```

If you had to use a for loop, then you can set a global variable that will track how many questions you answered overall (i.e addition of yes and no) and show question accordingly.

Also in your code, your for loop condition is incorrect.